# Cannot find TData or TValue in the tanstack typescript library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, react-table

I am using react-table version 8 aka [Tanstack](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/guide/introduction) table. Why are the types TData and TValue not found? And what is the best way to handle this?

I have a function that takes an argument of type Cell.
If I just write the fn like this,

```
 const getCellValue = (cell: Cell<TData, TValue>): void => {
    // .. function body
  }
```

I get the error...
[image]

So I added the 2 type arguments like so...

```
 const getCellValue = (cell: Cell<TData, TValue>): void => {
    // .. function body
  }
```

These type arguments TData and TValue are not found in the tanstack library.
[image]

What is the solution?
New to typescript and new to tanstack.
Perhaps I'm importing TData and TValue improperly?
Perhaps the Tanstack type files are not complete?
Perhaps I need to use a different type rather than `Cell` in my file.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/core/table) we found that:

```
data: TData[]
```

So, **TData** is our table data type, you can use your data interface here. For example, **Order[]**, **Todo[]**, etc.

A generic type table can be implemented as follows:

```
import {
  ColumnDef,
  useReactTable,
  ...
} from "@tanstack/react-table";

interface ReactTableProps<TData> {
  data: TData[];
  columns: ColumnDef<TData>[];
}

const ReactTable = <TData extends object>({
  data,
  columns,
}: ReactTableProps<TData>) => {
  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  });

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

and **TValue** is the value type (string, number, etc.).

Here is the example:

[image: Edit beautiful-currying-ih7vmi]